# How support +Y up in glTF?

Tags: gltf

glTF uses a right-handed coordinate system, that is, the cross product of +X and +Y yields +Z. glTF defines **+Y as up**. The front of a glTF asset faces +Z.

My question:
If the source format(such as .stl) uses a +Z up system, how convert +Z up in source format into the glTF +Y up?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details about what you've tried, which converter(s) you're working with, any languages or scripts or applications you're working with, etc?  The way it's worded now, it sounds like you're asking for a set of best practices on converting models.  That's too broad for a Stack Overflow question, but there are other sites and blogs out there that might cover it.

Comment: @emackey I am using C++ to convert source .stl file into glTF file. The source .stl file(contains a standing person on the ground) uses +Z up system, and if there is no any transform applied for source stl mesh, when viewing target gltf file, a possible result is that the person will lie instead of standing on the ground. My initial idea is to apply a transform on source mesh. I want to know whether there is any other better way.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to add a top-level node in the glTF scene, with a 90 degree rotation about the X axis, moving +Z to +Y.  All existing meshes could then be children of that node, and keep their Z-up vertices.